# Can I use a "\n" character in strings that are to be translated with Qt Linguist

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on supporting different languages for our GUI. I'm having a problem translating strings that have a '\n' in them. They seem to be ignored.

In Qt Designer I have a QCheckBox with this in the text field:

```
Here's an \nexample that doesn't work
```

This appears in english in our french translation.

Having looked at the .ts XML it seems that the text after the '\n' is ommited (I guess this is why it doesn't get translated ?)

Does anyone have a way of including a newline in the original text?

---

Seems I had carriage returns in my text before the newline. (no idea how they got there)

e.g

```
Here's an [][][][]\nexample that doesn't work
```

After removing them, the translation worked.

Comment: "\n " string how to translate QT linguistic, i cant able to find the answers.. Can u help me to this answer.. Links are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "\n" character itself was not my problem.

Some invisible carriage returns in the string was the culprit.

See http://qt.nokia.com/developer/task-tracker/index_html?method=entry&id=81275

Answer (score 2):

Use the [HTML subset](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html#supported-tags): `"Here's an <br />example that does work"`.