# Avoiding a new line character in QT Linguistic

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

How to make a "\n" new line character with the translation of String to Qt Linguistic. The translation is not working.

```
QString com = "Communication & \n Speech";

QLabel *Heading = new QLabel();

Heading.setText(QLabel::tr(com));


japanese_jn.ts

     <message>
        <source>Communication &amp; \n Speech</source>
        <translation>コミュニケーションとスピーチ</translation>
    </message>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use a "\n" character in strings that are to be translated with Qt Linguist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491537/can-i-use-a-n-character-in-strings-that-are-to-be-translated-with-qt-linguist)